# Fail message not showing on frontpage - SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am new to SvelteKit.

I was looking for a YouTube tutorial about form validation and I came across this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTI5oZM3buo

Everything went well but when I wanted to pass an errormessage to the frontend saying the passwords did not match, I received the error in the console, but the message didn't show up for the user to see.

The code is kinda basic and easy understandable so even me, a newbie to Svelte, didn't see what is wrong with the code.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

My form:

```html
<script>
    import { useForm, validators, HintGroup, Hint, email, required} from "svelte-use-form";
    // @ts-ignore
    import Logo from "/src/components/Logo.svelte";
    export let form;
  </script>

<form method="POST" action="/register?/create">
    {#if form?.error}
        <div class="error">
            <p>{form.error}</p>
        </div>
    {/if}

    <label for="email">Full name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required />

    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required />

    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required />

    <label for="password">Bevestig wachtwoord</label>
        <input type="password" name="requirePassword" required />
  
    <button>Login</button>

    <p>Nog geen account?<a href="google.com">Registreer hier</a></p>
</form>
```

My +page.server.js

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const actions = {
    create: async({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const username = data.get('name')
        const email = data.get('email')
        const password = data.get('password')
        const confirmed = data.get('requirePassword')
        console.log({username, email, password, confirmed})

        if (password !== confirmed) {
            return fail(422, {
                error: 'Wachtwoorden komen niet met elkaar overeen'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `form` properly declared as a prop? I.e. `export let form`?

Comment: Also would recommend the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance) and removing `/register` from the action if that is the current route.

Comment: @H.B. I've imported my props in my code! Take a look.

Comment: @H.B. Can you show me what you mean by that?

Comment: Translates to this on the form: `action="?/create" use:enhance`, see link to docs in previous comment for more details. As noted, changing the action like this only makes sense if this is the `/register` route.

Comment: Now I don't even get an error message, even tho I should get one..

Comment: The browser dev tools network panel should give you more information on what happens with the requests. The console should show any JS issues. You don't have to change the `action`, it would just be a simplification that is possible if the page belongs to the route the action is on.

Comment: If you intended to link to the tutorial this is based on, the link is missing.

Comment: The network tab even shows me an 200 okay..

Comment: I've included the link

Comment: Just of note, would it not be a good idea to also include the id value and just mimic the name value there so that in case you have other pure javascript elements you they can easily select the element by that id.

Comment: I would say yes, but this form isn't anything sophisticated, so I'm good for now

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

I totally forgot about adding a display:none on the element so even tho there would be an error, it would be prevented from showing.

Comment: And you probably know but you can toggle that to display:block to get it to show when a message is required.

Comment: is that even necessary..? It works fine without display: block too

Comment: Not exactly, but when its set to display:none , it won't show anything, or display:block would show something.  So when it has a message to display, it would need to be displayed to block but its possible something else you have is already doing that, just making you aware of the process as its used like everywhere in javascript for things like that.